# Jexcel - Updating an excel with data

Tags: excel, jxl

I've tried using [Jexcel](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/index.html)

to update an existing excel sheet as discussed in the Vogella [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/).

Issue here is the data already present in the existing excel sheet is wiped out with the newly written excel data.

For example if I've this in the excel

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td> <td>2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td> <td>4 </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

and I want to add data to the new cell next to 2 and 4, like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td> <td>2 </td> <td>X </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td> <td>4 </td> <td>Y </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

after the write program executed this is what I get

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> </td> <td>  </td> <td>X </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td> <td>  </td> <td>Y </td>
</tr>
<table>

Label label;
label = new Label(column, row, s, times);
sheet.addCell(label);
```

This is adding the cell at the specified column and row but wiping out the rest of the excel data.

How can I add data to the existing excel keeping the data?

Following is the program(Reference: Vogella).  Excel sheet already has data in 20 rows and
first 2 columns, am trying to add data on the 3rd column for 20 rows
    package excel;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import jxl.CellView;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.format.UnderlineStyle;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableFont;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

public class WriteExcel {

    private WritableCellFormat timesBoldUnderline;
    private WritableCellFormat times;
    private String inputFile;

    public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
        WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        createLabel(excelSheet);
        createContent(excelSheet);

        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
    }

    private void createLabel(WritableSheet sheet) throws WriteException {
        // Lets create a times font
        WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10);
        // Define the cell format
        times = new WritableCellFormat(times10pt);
        // Lets automatically wrap the cells
        times.setWrap(true);

        // Create create a bold font with unterlines
        WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(
                WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false,
                UnderlineStyle.SINGLE);
        timesBoldUnderline = new WritableCellFormat(times10ptBoldUnderline);
        // Lets automatically wrap the cells
        timesBoldUnderline.setWrap(true);

        CellView cv = new CellView();
        cv.setFormat(times);
        cv.setFormat(timesBoldUnderline);
        cv.setAutosize(true);

    }

    private void createContent(WritableSheet sheet) throws WriteException,
            RowsExceededException {

        Integer salary = 1000;
        // Now a bit of text
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            // third column
            addLabel(sheet, 2, i, salary.toString());

            // WritableCell cell = sheet.getWritableCell(2, i);
            // if (cell.getType() == CellType.LABEL) {
            // Label l = (Label) cell;
            // l.setString("modified cell");
            // }
            salary += 1000;
        }

    }

    private void addLabel(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
            throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
        Label label;
        label = new Label(column, row, s, times);
        sheet.addCell(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws WriteException, IOException {
        WriteExcel test = new WriteExcel();
        test.setOutputFile("c:/temp/lars.xls");
        test.write();
        System.out
                .println("Please check the result file under c:/temp/lars.xls ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Another framework [DataFile](http://datafile.sourceforge.net/) does not seem to have any API on DataRow to add data at a particular cell(row, column).

Comment: what's the code that you are using to create the workbook ?

Comment: Added the code above.  Please check.

Comment: did the provided solution worked ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `WritableWorkbook` which creates a NEW writable work book over writing the previous one. To modify the existing workbook you will first have to create a copy of the existing workbook something like below :

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("myfile.xls")); 
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"), workbook);
```

and then work on the copy. For more detailed info see (Path where you have extracted the api)\jexcelapi\src\jxl\demo\ReadWrite.java or navigate to Copying and Modifying Spreadsheets of [this](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html) page.

Comment: The following (unfortunately rejected) edit suggestion could be useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3928864